# Dijkstra's Algorithm Java, path error when use multiple source

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, vertex

I found Dijkstra's Algorithm from internet [(here the original code)](http://www.algolist.com/code/java/Dijkstra's_algorithm) , and I try to use multiple source instead multiple destination. But when I run the code, output isn't right, it just shows first vertex for all output.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}

class Edge {

    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) {
        target = argTarget;
        weight = argWeight;
    }

}

public class tes_dijkstra {

    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();
            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);
                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertex v0 = new Vertex("Redvile");
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("Blueville");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Greenville");
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex("Orangeville");
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Purpleville");

        v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 5),
                                     new Edge(v2, 10),
                                     new Edge(v3, 8) };
        v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 5),
                                     new Edge(v2, 3),
                                     new Edge(v4, 7) };
        v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 10),
                                     new Edge(v1, 3) };
        v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 8),
                                     new Edge(v4, 2) };
        v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 7),
                                 new Edge(v3, 2) };
        Vertex[] start = { v1, v2, v3, v4 };
        Vertex[] end ={v2};

        for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < end.length; j++){
                computePaths(start[i]);
                System.out.println("Distance to " + end[j] + ": " + end[j].minDistance);
                List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(end[j]);
                System.out.println("Path: " + path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how the output looks like :

```
Distance to Greenville: 3.0
Path: [Blueville, Greenville]
Distance to Greenville: 0.0
Path: [Blueville, Greenville]
Distance to Greenville: 0.0
Path: [Blueville, Greenville]
Distance to Greenville: 0.0
Path: [Blueville, Greenville]
```

The output just shows first vertex from Vertex[] start (v1 = Blueville) for all output.
I don't know where is wrong, is path stored somewhere? I kinda new in java and I want to learn this algorithm for my assignment, so please help. Thank you

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger,examine values, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the vertices store information about the cost and the path that is constructed. The problem is not that much that the path itself is constructed but the `minDistance` is the distance from a given start vertex. You can implement a method `reset` in the `Vertex` class

```
void reset () {
    this.minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

And furthermore you need to reset *all* vertices of the graph when you want to perform the next Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertex v0 = new Vertex("Redvile");
    Vertex v1 = new Vertex("Blueville");
    Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Greenville");
    Vertex v3 = new Vertex("Orangeville");
    Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Purpleville");

    v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 5),
                                 new Edge(v2, 10),
                                 new Edge(v3, 8) };
    v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 5),
                                 new Edge(v2, 3),
                                 new Edge(v4, 7) };
    v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 10),
                                 new Edge(v1, 3) };
    v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 8),
                                 new Edge(v4, 2) };
    v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 7),
                             new Edge(v3, 2) };
    Vertex[] start = { v1, v2, v3, v4 };
    Vertex[] end = {v2};
    Vertex[] all = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4};

    for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < end.length; j++){
            computePaths(start[i]);
            System.out.println("Distance to " + end[j] + ": " + end[j].minDistance);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(end[j]);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }
        //a new start vertex: reset the graph
        for(Vertex v : all) {
            v.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implement reset in vertex class solve the problem, and besides resetting minDistance, I reset vertex.previous too.. thank you so much CommuSoft, you really help me understand how this algorithm works.